# ReactJS Как правильно организовать редактирование сущности?

Tags: reactjs

Изучаю web-программирование с бэкграундом разработки десктопных приложений и конфигурирования 1С:Предприятия.
Начинаю изучать react, не могу понять как мне организовать редактирование сущности.

Допустим, есть справочник, у справочника есть форма списка (здесь и далее "форма" - это набор элементов управления для ввода и просмотра данных, это не конкретно тег form) и форма редактирования. В терминах react - это два разных компонента, у каждого из которых есть свой route.

1. Как я понял есть два способа перейти из списка в форму редактирования:

   - сделать общий компонент для отрисовки списка и карточки сущности в зависимости от состояния некоторого флага. Этот вариант не очень нравится, т.к. два разных понятия доступны по одному url
   - изменять window.location.href. Выбрал этот вариант
2. Далее не понятно, как правильно передавать параметры из списка в форму редактирования. Можно передать через URL, но они тогда все будут на виду и это не очень красиво, и скорее всего не безопасно. Т.к. при изменении записи нужно передавать ее id, который не нужно нигде отображать.
3. Данные хранятся в базе, доступ к которой осуществляется через отдельное RestAPI приложение. Пока есть идея реализовать обмен параметрами через базу данных: сначала генерим некий ключ -> по ключу в базу сохраняем параметры -> ключ передаем через url -> в форме редактирования берем параметры из базы по ключу.
   Думаю, идея рабочая, но все это похоже на очередной велосипед.

Подскажите, как это делается на практике?